# Neural Networks for integer values

Tags: neural-network

I have approximately 5000 integer vectors (=SIZE) that look like:

```
[1 0 4 2 0 1 3 ...]
```

They have the same length N=32 and their values ranges from 0 to 4 but let's say [0 MAX].
I created a NN that takes vectors as inputs and outputs a binary array corresponding to one of the desired output(number of possible outputs = M):
for instance [0 1 0 0 ...0] => 2nd output. array_length = M
I used a Multi Layer Perceptron in Neuroph with those integer values but it did not converge. 
So I am guessing the problem is using integer values or using a MLP with 3 layers: input, hidden and output.

Can you advise me on the network structure? which type of NN is suitable? Should I remodel the input and output to simplify the learning process? I have been thinking about Gray encoding for the integers input.

Comment: Are the values numerical or categorical? Also it's hard to diagnose a problem where it won't converge. It could be a bug or bad hyperparameter settings, or any number of issues. Your best bet is to try a really simplified version of your task, like with 5 training examples with 2 features and 2 outputs. If that trains then you can rule out bugs, at least.

Comment: I don't understand the function you are trying to learn. Can you elaborate?

Comment: @Houshalter the values are numerical not categorical. I did what you said on a 3 layers MLP and it worked.

Comment: @cfh I have 30 outputs and 5000 static input vectors. Each vector is a possible representation of the output values. So the learning alogorithm has to match each input vector to the desired output. On the other hand, when the NN is functional, I'll input a random vector and analyze the output which is supposed to show the possible matching outputs among the 30 values.